# Slider's ThumbToolTipValueConverter with parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

```
<Slider ThumbToolTipValueConverter="{StaticResource ThumbConverter}"/>
```

I need to change value in `ThumbToolTip` based on `Slider.Value` and value from ViewModel (called `SecondValue`).

How can I pass `SecondValue` to `ThumbConverter`?
(How can I use `ConverterParameter` in here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of this:

Converter -

```
public class ThumbConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public double SecondValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(SecondValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SecondValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SecondValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SecondValue", typeof(double), typeof(ThumbConverter), new PropertyMetadata(0d));


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // assuming you want to display precentages

        return $"Precentage: {double.Parse(value.ToString()) / SecondValue}";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

the usage -

```
<Slider VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <Slider.ThumbToolTipValueConverter>

            <converters:ThumbConverter SecondValue="{Binding SecondValue}" />

        </Slider.ThumbToolTipValueConverter>

    </Slider>
```

Take note - the visual change will only occur when the Slider's value will change.
While the class itself will be notified on SecondValue's changes, the visual change will only happen should you change the slider's value.

The situation screams for the implementation of MultiValueConverter, but we don't have those in UWP. so this is the cleanest one I've got.